# Edit items order by drag and drop Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am using java swing to make the GUI of a robot. this GUI must contain a window which contains the tasks that will be executed by order. However this steps must be editable(drag a step to be in front of the others). Can this be accomplished using swing?

Comment: Which swing control should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tutorial can help you [Drag and Drop and Data Transfer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html).